# How good swimmer does one need to swim across the Saltstraumen?

Tags: swimming

I have just read [a story from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/outdoorswimmingsociety/permalink/10157756959577830/) from someone who has just swum across the Saltstraumen. How good swimmer does one need to be in order to make it across in time?

Comment: **Very** good. How strong a swimmer do you imagine you need to be to cross one of the world's fastest tidal currents? Perhaps this story at the [Outdoor Swimming Society](https://www.outdoorswimmingsociety.com/into-the-maelstrom/) by two brothers who made the crossing is of interest.

Comment: @WeatherVane reading your link I have the distinct impression they swam the critical points at the tidal slack point, i.e. the point at which the tides is switching between ebb and flood.  Not to diss their achievement, but I suspect that leaves a big fat "not doable wo considerable risk" on taking on the area during its full current strength.  A guide book for kayakers in BC was very clear on the dangers:  author tried to dissuade a river white water  kayaker from taking on a rapid (Hole in the Wall?).  Guy didn't listen, but luckily they fished him out a bit later and he didn't drown.

Comment: The channel is indeed considered not navigable during its full current strength. It is only possible to cross it at that critical moment.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica of couse the tide was slack but it was no mill pond and timing was crucial. The article says "a frenetic 10-minute window", and they completed the crossing a minute before conditions changed and when they would have had to be rescued by the support crew. They also claim to be the first, so it is definitely only for well prepared experts, and I guess the 'considerable risk' still applies.